# Chrome 39 JavaScript Performance Anomaly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

I did [a jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/variable-vs-variable-passed-as-an-argument-to-a-self-in/2) to see if there were any performance differences between using arguments or local variables in a function in JavaScript.

In Firefox 34, there was practically no difference. However, in Chrome 39, the compiler seems to be doing a lot of harm. See these results:

[image]

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Just for the record, equal results in IE 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all for a benchmark that tries to measure arguments vs. local variables performance behavior you are doing **too much** in the each case - you allocate a closure again and again, you allocate object from object literal, you use for-in loop. All these operations are way **more** expensive than local variable access. Their costs subsume and hide whatever small cost variable access has.

Now the anomaly you are seeing is due to V8 not having a fast path for creating closures that contain literals: there is `FastNewClosureStub` but it is only used when there are no literals in the closure[1]. This makes closure allocation more expensive in the first case compared to the second - you are seeing this reflected in the score as closure allocation is rather dominant part of your benchmark (it allocates one closure per *op*).

If you "hide" literal creation[2] into a separate function you will see anomaly going away. Note: such hiding doesn't make benchmark anymore representative: it is still **not** measuring what you want to measure.

Overall trying to capture performance characteristics of variable access in a benchmark is very hard because these are usually among the fastest and smallest operations even in the code produced by non-optimizing (baseline) compiler. In the most common case when no variables are captured and the scope does not contain `with`, `eval` or `arguments` object - there'll be no difference between arguments and local variable access both compiling down into a single memory load.

[1] https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/9def087efcd844342c35f42628bac4ead49cac81/src/ia32/full-codegen-ia32.cc#L1213-L1218

[2] http://jsperf.com/variable-vs-variable-passed-as-an-argument-to-a-self-in/3